# postgres permission issue when logged in as a user

Tags: postgresql

I know this is a db question and I posted the question there and didn't get any response. If anyone can help, it would be great. I even followed the instructions on here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-postgresql-user-account/ but no luck.

I'm logged in as a user in postgres with PgAdmin tool in Linux connecting remotely but I don't think the user has enough rights. I'm a MySQL experienced user but not so much in PostGres. When I select a table when logged in as the user I get

An error has occurred:

ERROR: permission denied for relation acs_activities

how do I add my user "gainpm" to have access to all tables in "projop" database?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. First I had to login as superuser

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

then issue

```
ALTER USER myuser WITH SUPERUSER;
```

Comment: Doesnt work for me. sudo -u postgres psql
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.